# I want to delete own player object, but I can't use Destroy | PUN2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I am making a shooter game using PUN2, but I encountered a problem where the players did not disappear.
Player movement, shell movement using PunRPC, bullet handling, etc. are implemented.

I do *Destroy()* the player when the player's health becomes 0 with the following code.

**Player.cs** :

```
GameObject Player; // player object attached
int HP = 100; 

//If hit
public void Damaged(int damage)
{
    photonView.RPC(nameof(UpdateHP), RpcTarget.All, damage)
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateHP(int damage)
{
    HP -= damage;
    if(HP <= 0)
        photonView.RPC(nameof(RemovePlayer), RpcTarget.All);

    var hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable["HP"] = HP;
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(hashtable);
}

[PunRPC]
void RemovePlayer()
{
    Destroy(Player)
}
```

Flow: Execute **Damaged(int)** in **Player.cs** from the shell script, calculate the physical strength with *PunRPC*, and if it is less than 0, execute **RemovePlayer()** with *PunRPC*.

Calling **photonView.RPC(nameof(RemovePlayer), RpcTarget.All);** will generate an error.

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

---

Also, When I use **Destroy()** without *PunRPC*, it will only disappear from his device and remain visible to other players.

**Destroy() without PunRPC** :

```
GameObject Player; // player object attached
int HP = 100; 

//If hit
public void Damaged(int damage)
{
    photonView.RPC(nameof(UpdateHP), RpcTarget.All, damage)
}

[PunRPC]
void UpdateHP(int damage)
{
    HP -= damage;
    if(HP <= 0)
        RemovePlayer();

    var hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable["HP"] = HP;
    PhotonNetwork.LocalPlayer.SetCustomProperties(hashtable);
}

void RemovePlayer()
{
    Destroy(Player)
}
```

Comment: Try using [PhotonNetwork.Destroy()](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a75f0f61ec71729b782a9da6bbad86e97). You can pass either a GameObject, or a PhotonView.

Comment: Also do you really need this? usually Photon destroyes the instances of a removed player anyway ...

Comment: I think the error in this code is not directly related to Destroy. 
Is PhotonNetwork.Destroy() or Destroy() not allowed in [PunRPC]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mrPhilipp said, by executing PhotonNetwork.Destroy () I was able to completely delete the object. This was possible outside of [PunRPC].